# How to update font path?

Tags: fonts, openbsd

I am using OpenBSD 5.5 and have just installed a package named xpdf

The installation completed with the following message:

```
You may wish to update your font path for /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts
```

What exactly do I need to do?

Comment: If you want to do it system-wide, you will need to edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (note that if it doesn't exist it has to be created and properly filled, which might not be that simple. See `man 5 xorg.conf`).

If you only want to set if for your user, you just need to add `xset +fp /usr/local/lib/share/ghostscript/fonts` to `~/.xinitrc`.

How do you start X?

Comment: @ZéLoff During installation of OpenBSD 5.5, a question was asked of me whether I wanted to start the xdm automatically. I answered _yes_

Comment: @ZéLoff Are there any pdf readers or creators which are way bettr than xpdf? It seems there is no individual package called evince available at OpenBSD's packages directory.

Comment: There is an `evince` package for OpenBSD 5.5 at least for `i386` and `amd64` architectures (I didn't check the others). You can find packages using something like `pkg_info -Q evince` and install them with `pkg_add evince`. If it complains about not finding them make sure you have _either_ set the `PKG_PATH` environment variable _or_ an appropriate `installpath` address at `pkg.conf`. See `man 7 packages`.

Comment: Regarding the PDF readers, I mostly use `mupdf` for viewing (very lightweight and keyboard-centric), switching to `xpdf` if I need to print something. Creating PDFs is another matter altogether and mostly depends on what you are "printing". For example, LibreOffice and Firefox allow you to "print" directly to PDF, you have `cups-pdf` if you want a "PDF printer" and there is always `ghostscript`, if you need something more low-level...

Comment: If you use xdm then I don't think editing `.xinitrc` will do, and you should look add the `xset +fp ...` to .xsession. `man 1 xdm` might also help.

Comment: @ZéLoff: Is cups-pdf a package or a driver that LibreOffice and Firefox use?

Comment: It's a package. LibreOffice, Firefox, etc print to PDF directly, without requiring it.